# Java - Split String by Number and Letters

Tags: java, regex, string, split, q

So I have, for example, a string such as this `C3H20IO`

What I wanna do is split this string so I get the following:

```
Array1 = {C,H,I,O}
Array2 = {3,20,1,1}
```

The `1` as the third element of the `Array2` is indicative of the monoatomic nature of the `I` element. Same for `O`. That is actually the part I am struggling with.

This is a chemical equation, so I need to separate the elements according to their names and the amount of atoms there are etc.

Comment: How did you get the last two entries 1,1 in array2, your input string is C3H20IO doesn't have it.

Comment: The tricky part is that monatomic components are not proceeded by a number.  I would love to see a slick Java 8 streams solution to this.

Comment: @ClementAmarnath It seems `1,1` indicates monoatomic `I` and `O`

Comment: Exactly. The monoatomic numbers are supposed to get 1 while never actually having a number.  I was thinking about using a for loop after toCharArray but not sure again about the monoatomic components.

Comment: You are not the first to parse formulas, check these out for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bchemistry%5d%20formula

Comment: @Vixen Thanks, I actually somehow did not thinking of searching for Chemistry Parsing. I am a very recent beginner to programming in general and hell, i am even having trouble understanding the regex expression some are using but its helpful to get answers in Java rather than try to work from other languages and try to translate them to Java etc. Thanks anyhow, i will be trying to understand it. :)

Comment: @Azazel See my answer using ``Map``. Hope it will help you!

Comment: @mmuzahid Thanks for the answer. I am sure it was perfect on its own but to me it doesn't make much sense since i am not that knowledgable on Maps etc. Good for my learning though so thankyou. :)

Comment: @Azazel I removed the ``Map`` and modified using ``List``. Now hope it make sense to you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try this approach:

```
String formula = "C3H20IO";

//insert "1" in atom-atom boundry 
formula = formula.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=\\D)$", "1");

//split at letter-digit or digit-letter boundry
String regex = "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)";
String[] atoms = formula.split(regex);
```

Output:

> atoms: [C, 3, H, 20, I, 1, O, 1]

Now all even even indices (0, 2, 4...) are atoms and odd ones are the associated number:

```
String[] a = new String[ atoms.length/2 ];
int[] n = new int[ atoms.length/2 ];

for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
    a[i] = atoms[i*2];
    n[i] = Integer.parseInt(atoms[i*2+1]);
}
```

Output:

> a: [C, H, I, O]
>   n: [3, 20, 1, 1]

Comment: This seems really good. I am gonna give it a try and see what happens. Thanks. Will update soon.

Comment: Works beautifully and for a beginner like it makes at least a little bit sense. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that atoms may be abbreviated with multiple letters: Ag, Au, Mg etc.

Comment: @AmazingDreams that's a good point, I fixed the code (assuming that the usual notation of having the second letter lowercase is respected), by inserting `"1"` only between letters if they are both uppercase

Comment: I am using this but unfortunately have run into a small issue. In some cases, i am given a NumberFormatException on the `n[i] = Integer.parseInt(atoms[i*2+1])`. I am not sure why. Do you have any idea why it might be?

Comment: @Azazel could you show us some examples where you get that exception?

Comment: I have been trying to re-create it but am having trouble. I am going to do a lot more intense testing and will let you know if i do find an example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regular expression to slide over your input using the **Matcher.find()** method.

Here a rough example of what it may look like:

```
    String input = "C3H20IO";

    List<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z][a-z]*)([0-9]*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);               
    while(matcher.find()){
        array1.add(matcher.group(1));

        String atomAmount = matcher.group(2);
        int atomAmountInt = 1;
        if((atomAmount != null) && (!atomAmount.isEmpty())){
            atomAmountInt = Integer.valueOf(atomAmount);
        }
        array2.add(atomAmountInt);
    }
```

I know, the conversion from List to Array is missing, but it should give you an idea of how to approach your problem.

Answer (score 4):

An approach without `REGEX` and data stored using `ArrayList`:

```
String s = "C3H20IO";

char Chem = '-';
String val = "";
boolean isFisrt = true;
List<Character> chemList = new ArrayList<Character>();
List<Integer> weightList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        if (!isFisrt) {
            chemList.add(Chem);
            weightList.add(Integer.valueOf(val.equals("") ? "1" : val));
            val = "";
        }
        Chem = c;
    } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        val += c;
    } 
    isFisrt = false;
}
chemList.add(Chem);
weightList.add(Integer.valueOf(val.equals("") ? "1" : val));

System.out.println(chemList);
System.out.println(weightList);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[C, H, I, O]
[3, 20, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

This works assuming each element starts with a capital letter, i.e. if you have "Fe" you don't represent it in String as "FE". Basically, you split the string on each capital letter then split each new string by letters and numbers, adding "1" if the new split contains no numbers.

```
        String s = "C3H20IO";
        List<String> letters = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] arr = s.split("(?=\\p{Upper})");  // [C3, H20, I, O]
        for (String str : arr) {  //[C, 3]:[H, 20]:[I]:[O]
            String[] temp = str.split("(?=\\d)", 2);
            letters.add(temp[0]);
            if (temp.length == 1) {
                numbers.add("1");
            } else {
                numbers.add(temp[1]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(letters)); //[[C, H, I, O]]
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(numbers)); //[[3, 20, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: in `.split()`, you may use the second argument to limit number of results, so your second split can be simplified to `temp = str.split("(?=\\d)", 2)`

Answer (score 1):

make (for loop) with size of input length and add following condition

```
if(i==number)
// add it to the number array

if(i==character)
//add it into character array
```

Comment: Ok. Understood. I actually have already done that. The main issue is with the monoatomic components.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest splitting by uppercase letter using zero-width lookahead regex (to extract items like `C12`, `O2`, `Si`), then split each item into element and its numeric weight:

```
List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> weights = new ArrayList<>();

String[] items = "C6H12Si6OH".split("(?=[A-Z])");  // [C6, H12, Si6, O, H]
for (String item : items) {
    String[] pair = item.split("(?=[0-9])", 2);    // e.g. H12 => [H, 12], O => [O]
    elements.add(pair[0]);
    weights.add(pair.length > 1 ? Integer.parseInt(pair[1]) : 1);
}
System.out.println(elements);  // [C, H, Si, O, H]
System.out.println(weights);   // [6, 12, 6, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

**I did this as following**

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerCharacters = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> stringCharacters = new ArrayList<>();

String value = "C3H20IO"; //Your value 
String[] strSplitted = value.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"); //Split numeric and strings

for(int i=0; i<strSplitted.length; i++){

    if (Character.isLetter(strSplitted[i].charAt(0))){
        stringCharacters.add(strSplitted[i]); //If string then add to strings array
    }
    else{
        integerCharacters.add(Integer.parseInt(strSplitted[i])); //else add to integer array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this good? (Not using `split`)

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG5cD9/1)**

```
String line = "C3H20ZnO2ABCD";
String pattern = "([A-Z][a-z]*)(((?=[A-Z][a-z]*|$))|\\d+)";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

while (m.find( )) {
     System.out.print(m.group(1));
     if (m.group(2).length() == 0) {
         System.out.println(" 1");
     } else {
         System.out.println(" " + m.group(2));
     }
  }
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/yQ6bEt)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use two patterns :

- [0-9]
- [a-zA-Z]

Split twice by each of them.

```
List<String> letters = Arrays.asList(test.split("[0-9]"));
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList(test.split("[a-zA-Z]"))
            .stream()
            .filter(s -> !s.equals(""))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

if(letters.size() != numbers.size()){
        numbers.add("1");
    }
```

Comment: What about the case of single atoms, e.g. in `H_2_O` there is no number after the oxygen atom.

Comment: That is actually the main issue for me. I figured out that using Split with those Regex patterns would work but that is the pain.

Comment: Only last atom can be without a number?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by using a regular expression like (?<=\D)(?=\d). Try this :

```
String alphanum= "abcd1234";
String[] part = alphanum.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
System.out.println(part[0]);
System.out.println(part[1]);
```

will output

abcd
1234

Comment: What about the monoatomic components?