# How to seperate a char and num in a string and print the char repeated times of num

Tags: java

Write a java programm to print a output like this

input : `d3f4cf5`
output `dddffffcfcfcfcfcf`

```
 for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++)
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
            {r = str.charAt(i);
                for(r=1;r<=i;r++) {
                System.out.println(str.substring(t, i));
                t = ++i;
                 }
            }
            if (i==str.length()-1) {
                for (r = 1; r <= i; r++) {
                    System.out.println(str.substring(t));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Split String by Number and Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423633/java-split-string-by-number-and-letters)

Comment: I recommend using Stringbuilder to append the character each time you need to, then printing the full string at the end.

Comment: @Nexevis as of Java 9 that [isn't necessary anymore](https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-9jep-280-string-concatenations-will-never-be-t), in fact you now should [use `+` rather than `StringBuilder` (page 39)](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/talks/pdfs/2018%20Voxxed%20in%20Thessaloniki,%20Greece%20-%20"Enough%20java.lang.String%20to%20Hang%20Ourselves%20..."%20by%20Heinz%20Kabutz.pdf) - note that I assume you're referring to the memory and performance implications of string concatenations. If you're refering to the OP printing to often then ignore the reference to your comment :)

Comment: @Thomas Yeah I am referring to how he wants to print a character every time instead of storing it as a String then printing it all at once.  We don't know what version of Java he is using either.

Comment: @Nexevis you're right we don't. However, I'd assume (hope) that for learning purposes (and that's what it looks like) they're using current versions of Java (with Java 9 already being "old").

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Ronald suggested you could split your string and run over the arrays.

For how to split have a look here: [Java - Split String by Number and Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423633/java-split-string-by-number-and-letters)

Let's assume we then just have the array `["d","3","f","4","cf","5"]`. You then could do something like this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2 ) {
  String letters = array[i];
  int count = Integer.parseInt( array[i + 1] );

  //loop and print here
}
```

Note that this always expects the string to start with at least one letter and end with a number. If it doesn't you'd have to handle that explicitly, i.e. don't print anything for the first number if it starts with a number (that could be done by just "printing" an empty string n times) and assume a count of 1 if the input ends with letters.

If you can't use regular expressions for some reason you could also do it while iterating over the characters of the string. You'd then use a combination of the following steps:

1. If the character is a letter you're in string building mode. You add the character to a temporay string. Initially that temporary string would be empty.
2. If the character is a digit you're in counting mode. You add the digit to a temporary counter (which you'd first multiply with 10 if you want to support more than one digit numbers). The counter would initially have the value 0.
3. When you switch from counting mode to string building mode you print the current temporary string as often as you've counted, then reset the counter to 0 and the temporary string to empty (`""`) and repeat step 1 (you add the current character to the temp string).
4. When you hit the end of the input you do the same as in step 3. If you need to support input ending in letters you'd probably want to assume a count of 1 so before executing step 3 you'd set the counter (which should still be 0) to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is well formed something like below should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String input = "d3f4cf5";
    System.out.println(uncompress(input));
}

private static String uncompress(String input) {
    //Split input at each number and keep the numbers
    // for the given input this produces [d3, f4, cf5]
    String[] parts = input.split("(?<=\\d+)");            
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String str : parts){
       // remove letters to get the number
       int n    = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
       // remove numbers to get the letters
       String s = str.replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
       // append n copies of string to sb
       sb.append(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(n, s)));
    }        
    return sb.toString();
}
```